# Lost String in Parcelable

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, parcel

I'm creating an alarm clock app and i have a problem with passing the data about repeating days in parcel. I thought that it might be something with boolean array so i switched it to String but still problem remains.

Any idea what is wrong with my Parcelable object?

```
public Alarm(Parcel source) {
    mHour = source.readInt();
    mMinutes = source.readInt();
    mId = source.readInt();

    // Here string is empty ""
    String days = source.readString();  
    mDays = GeneralUtilities.daysStringToBoolean(days);

    mIsEnabled = source.readInt() != 0;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(mHour);
    dest.writeInt(mMinutes);
    dest.writeLong(mId);

    // Here days is string "True,False ... "
    String days = GeneralUtilities.daysBooleanToString(mDays);
    dest.writeString(days);

    dest.writeInt((mIsEnabled ? 1 : 0));
}

public static final Creator<Alarm> CREATOR = new Creator<Alarm>() {
    @Override
    public Alarm createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Alarm(source);
    }

    @Override
    public Alarm[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Alarm[size];
    }
};
```

}

Comment: `mId = source.readInt();` should be `mId = source.readLong();`

Comment: oh god! i totally missed that. Thanks!